# How to filter the result whose type is array in loopback 4?

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback4

```
import {Entity, model, property} from '@loopback/repository';

@model()
export class Misc extends Entity {
  @property({
    type: 'number',
    id: true,
    generated: true,
  })
  id?: number;

  @property({
    type: 'array',
    itemType: 'number',
    required: true,
  })
  members: number[];


  constructor(data?: Partial<Misc>) {
    super(data);
  }
}

export interface MiscRelations {
  // describe navigational properties here
}

export type MiscWithRelations = Misc & MiscRelations;
```

Above is the model for misc API. I am using PostgreSQL.

I have inserted data in the table. Result of GET request from this table is as following -

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "members":[
         1,
         2,
         3
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "members":[
         1,
         2,
         3,
         4,
         5
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "members":[
         10,
         20,
         30,
         40,
         50
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":4,
      "members":[
         100,
         200,
         300,
         400,
         500
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":5,
      "members":[
         1,
         2,
         3,
         500,
         1000,
         5000
      ]
   }
]
```

I want to get the records who have members with value 1, so I applied a filter like this -

http://localhost:3000/miscs?filter[where][inq][members]=1

But this isn't working. If there is no way to execute such a query then can I do some change in the model to adjust its type such that it can accept CSV values and also can filter those data?

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found an answer. Regex can be used to match the record here like this

filter[where][members][regexp]=1,|1]

Answer (score 0):

For the Postgresql connector, use `contains`, which accepts an array:

```
?filter[where][contains][members][0]=1

- SAME AS -

{
  where: {
    contains: [1]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this doesn't work as intended! Is there any way I can modify the member field to some other type and apply the filter ? I think these kind of thing is possible if mongodb was used.